# Bokeh: Upon callback, the new plot is overlaid on top of the old plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to embed my plots. I have Select widgets for x-axis and y-axis selection. The plot gets updated as expected when I change the y-axis (fig 1); however, changing x-axis is giving me problems. 
Upon changing the x-axis option, the new line graph gets overlaid on top of the old graph (fig 2). Only when I refresh the page, the graph is rendered as expected (fig 3). How can I refresh my plot without having to refresh the entire page?

This is the working example of what I am trying:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.embed import server_session

document = Document()
session = push_session(document)

trip_data = [{"trip": '1', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.66", "totalTimeTaken": "765083", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '2', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.63", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '3', "totalDistanceTravelled": "3.66", "totalTimeTaken": "602713", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"},
             {"trip": '4', "totalDistanceTravelled": "7.11", "totalTimeTaken": "2234282", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "ABC123", "driverName": "Anne"},
             {"trip": '5', "totalDistanceTravelled": "14.14", "totalTimeTaken": "1282369", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '6', "totalDistanceTravelled": "4.33", "totalTimeTaken": "748446", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "DEF345", "driverName": "Harry"},
             {"trip": '7', "totalDistanceTravelled": "10.66", "totalTimeTaken": "960362", "time": "1504189219256",
              "carRegNo": "XYZ890", "driverName": "Ron"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(trip_data)
drivers = df['driverName'].str.strip()
vehicles = df['carRegNo'].str.strip()
time_stamp = df['time'].astype(float)
total_distance_travelled = df['totalDistanceTravelled'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] = df['totalTimeTaken'].astype(float)
df['totalTimeTaken'] /= 1000 * 3600

# Create Input controls
x_axis = Select(title="X Axis", options=sorted(["Drivers", "Vehicle Reg. Number"]), value="Drivers")
y_axis = Select(title="Y Axis", options=sorted(["Distance Travelled (kms)", "Time Taken (hours)"]),
                value="Time Taken (hours)")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))
p = figure(x_range=[], y_range=Range1d(), plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="")

def update():
    print "UPDATE"
    col_key_values = {
        "Time Taken (hours)": 'totalTimeTaken',
        "Distance Travelled (kms)": 'totalDistanceTravelled'
    }

    x_map = {
        "Drivers": drivers,
        "Vehicle Reg. Number": vehicles
    }

    x_name = x_map[x_axis.value]
    x_y_values = {}
    for x in x_name.unique():
        x_y_values[x] = round(df.loc[x_name == x, col_key_values[y_axis.value]].astype(float).sum(), 2)
    source.data = dict(
        x=list(x_y_values.keys()),
        y=list(x_y_values.values())
    )
    p.y_range.start = min(x_y_values.values())-1
    p.y_range.end = max(x_y_values.values())+1
    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
    p.x_range.factors = list(x_y_values.keys())
    p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)
    print source.data
    return p

def on_x_change(attr, old, new):
    global x_axis
    x_axis.value = new
    update()


def on_y_change(attr, old, new):
    global y_axis
    y_axis.value = new
    update()


def create_layout():
    print 'CREATE LAYOUT'
    x_axis.on_change('value', on_x_change)
    y_axis.on_change('value', on_y_change)
    controls = column(children=[x_axis, y_axis])
    layout = column(children=[controls, update()])
    return layout


layout = create_layout()

html = u"""
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        %s
    </body>
</html>
""" % server_session(layout, session_id=session.id, relative_urls=False)

with io.open("sample.html", mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)

print(__doc__)

document.add_root(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\npress ctrl-C to exit")
    session.loop_until_closed()
```

Attachments:
[image: First plot]

[image: Second plot overlaid over first]

[image: Second plot after refreshing the webpage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redrawing the line with p.line() you should just update the source of the line with source.data.update(dict). Just have an empty source to draw the line at the beginning with no data.

Also update the source after you update the figure range

```
p = figure(x_range=[], y_range=Range1d(), plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="")
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':[],'y':[]})
p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)

def update():
    print "UPDATE"
    col_key_values = {
        "Time Taken (hours)": 'totalTimeTaken',
        "Distance Travelled (kms)": 'totalDistanceTravelled'
    }

    x_map = {
        "Drivers": drivers,
        "Vehicle Reg. Number": vehicles
    }

    x_name = x_map[x_axis.value]
    x_y_values = {}
    for x in x_name.unique():
        x_y_values[x] = round(df.loc[x_name == x, col_key_values[y_axis.value]].astype(float).sum(), 2)
    p.y_range.start = min(x_y_values.values())-1
    p.y_range.end = max(x_y_values.values())+1
    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
    p.x_range.factors = list(x_y_values.keys())
    source.data.update( dict(
        x=list(x_y_values.keys()),
        y=list(x_y_values.values())
    ))
```